# I want to join 2 files using awk, files may not be sorted

Tags: awk

I have 2 files.
First file:

```
1,10000,abc,hello,cust
2,123,bib,hi,cust1
3,34562,acb,bye,cust2
```

2nd file

```
b231,3,231
w123,1,111
```

I want to join the above 2 files using awk command based on 1st column in 1st file & 2nd column in 2nd file and output should be in the below format. I need all the records in 1st file with 1st field in 2nd file be 4th field in the output file. 1st field in the 1st file should be discarded. I tried join but Im always getting the 4th field as empty. So thought of finding a solution using awk. Please explain the solution as well.
Note: the file size would be GBs.
output file format

```
10000,abc,hello,b231,cust
123,bbb,hi,,cust1
34562,acb,bye,w123,cust2
```

Comment: Is one file significantly smaller than the other?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `awk` like this:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=","} FNR==NR {p[$2]=$1;next} {if(p[$1])print $2,$3,$4,p[$1],$5; else print $2,$3,$4,"",$5}' file2 file1
```

**Explanation:**

```
-F,            - sets the input field separator to a comma
BEGIN{OFS=","} - sets the output field separator to a comma at the start
FNR==NR{...}   - remembers second field of file2 in array p[] indexed by first field
```

The remainder of the script checks each line in file1 to see if we saw its first field in file2. If we did, it prints fields 2,3,4, the corresponding element from array p[] and field 5. If we did not see the first field in file2, it just prints the curremt record with an extra comma.